# Slickgrid - number of columns showed in dom

Tags: slickgrid

I'm about to test a website with Selenium. There is implemented a table with SlickGrid.

I have the Problem that when I read in a row i get only 29 columns but there were about 40 (in real).. This cause to 100% to the virtualised scrolling.

I'm wondering, what's the default amount of columns which appears in the dom?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to resolve how it's done and I can say it's a bit tricky. There is no such thing as a "default amount" of columns, this amount is getting computed, see below for a bit of technical details.

You can check the [slick.grid.js](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L1787) files line 1787. There is a function `cleanUpAndRenderCells()`. This is responsible for calculating and rendering the cells which aren't on the grids canvas. For example when you scroll the horizontal scrollbar, this function gets called and based on the direction of the scroll they check if the next set of cells aren't on canvas and can fit the canvas, they append the cells to the DOM.

---

**For the matter of reading the row values**

I see two possible ways of doing that using `javascript`.

- If you are using a [`data`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#constructor) array as datasource:

  ```
  data[grid.getSelectedRows()[0]]
  ```
- If you are using a [`DataView`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView) as datasource:

  ```
  grid.DataView.getItemById(0)
  ```

Both will return an Object with property names of columns.

---

However I'm not sure how/why would you integration test this, the slickgrid package is already tested, you can check it [here](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/tests/index.html).